# The version of GCC does not match the expected version

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I am working on Eclipse and I have an error on my project :

```
#error The version of GCC does not match the expected version   
(GCC4.8.3)  Project1_Exemple        Unknown Compiler's error markers
```

I would like to know where on Eclipse I can fix this error , is it on the launch configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

Set Compiler invocation command (set path to gcc) in the Eclipse's configuration (Project -> Properties -> C/C+++ Build -> Manage Configurations)